# how to fix issue with share button align all in one line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

hey so i'm trying to align all of the share icons in one line except for bottom below is sample of my code and any help will be appreciated thank you.

link for codepen [codepen.io/anon/pen/radZZJ](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/radZZJ)

HTML code

```
<div id="postsocialsharewrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" id="share" unchecked />
  <label for="share" class="label entypo-share"></label>
  <div class="postsocialshare">
    <ulss>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=<?php the_title(); ?>&url=<?php the_permalink();?>" ><liss class="entypo-twitter"></liss></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" ><liss class="entypo-facebook"></liss></a>
      <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?hl=en&url=<?php if(is_home()){echo home_url();}else{the_permalink();} ?>" ><liss class="entypo-gplus"></liss></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://tumblr.com/share/link?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&media=<?php echo $image->guid;?>&description=<?php echo rawurlencode(get_the_title()); ?>" ><liss class="entypo-tumblr"></liss></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://stumbleupon.com/submit?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&media=<?php echo $image->guid;?>&description=<?php echo rawurlencode(get_the_title()); ?>" ><liss class="entypo-stumbleupon"></liss></a>
    </ulss>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);

[class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
}

html {
  margin:0;
  padding:50px 0;
  background: #161616 url(http://i43.tinypic.com/sfgmc3.gif);
}

#postsocialsharewrapper {
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin: 40px auto;
  width:300px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{display:none;}

.cbox:checked + .label {
  color:#0e90d2;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.cbox:checked ~ .postsocialshare {
  transform:scale(1) translateY(20px);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1) translateY(20px);
}

.label {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  font-size:22px;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 10px;
  border-radius:10%;
  color:#0e90d2;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.postsocialshare {
  transform-origin:50% 0%;
  transform:scale(0) translateY(-190px);
  transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform:scale(0) translateY(-190px);
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
.postsocialshare ulss {
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:-5px auto 0;
  height:46px;
  width:300px;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

.postsocialshare ulss liss {
  font-size:17px;
  font-family: 'entypo-social';
  cursor:pointer;
  width:60px;
  margin:0;
  padding:12px 0;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
  color:#0e90d2;
  height:22px;
  opacity:0.4;
}

.postsocialshare ulss liss:hover {opacity:1 !important;color:red !important;}

.postsocialshare liss[class*="twitter"] {}
.postsocialshare liss[class*="gplus"] {}
.postsocialshare liss[class*="stumbleupon"] {}
.postsocialshare liss[class*="tumblr"] {}
.postsocialshare liss[class*="facebook"] {}

.postsocialshare ulss liss.entypo-tumblr:before {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  content:'\F315';
}

.postsocialshare ulss liss.entypo-facebook:before {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  content:'\F30C';
}

.postsocialshare ulss liss.entypo-gplus:before {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  content:'\F30F';
}

.postsocialshare ulss liss.entypo-stumbleupon:before {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  content:'\F31E';
}

.postsocialshare ulss liss.entypo-twitter:before {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  content:'\F309';
}

.label.entypo-share:before {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  content:'\E715';
  color: #0e90d2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are already aligned vertically, I am guessing you want them aligned horizontally.

`.postsocialshare ulss liss{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}`

Edit: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJEPGY

Comment: they are aligned but they all are going bottom i want them on right hand side of the button http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJEPGY

Comment: not very good with animations. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJEPGY closest I could get

Comment: the animation is almost still the same, comes up from top left. But it displays on the right side of the share button

Comment: you are welcome. Still coming out a bit of the top huh.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this i think it may help you

```
.postsocialshare ulss liss {
font-size:17px;
font-family: 'entypo-social';
cursor:pointer;
margin:0;
padding:12px 0;
text-align:center;
float:left;
color:#0e90d2;
height:22px;
opacity:0.4;
display:block;
width:10%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogqQzZ